# ngrok-where is the public url

Tags: ngrok

To create a public url . I am looking at this doc --> https://codeburst.io/public-urls-for-your-local-web-server-with-ngrok-fa80424eec5c

I have installed ngrok and can even run this command successfully

```
  ./ngrok help
```

but when I run

```
  ./ngrok http 5000
```

I dont get a public url. The doc says after executing that command, you will see that ngrok has given your application a public URL

I never get public URL where do I find it

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out
I should have put it in my environment path

Comment: could you expand on this a bit please